# Ansible: wait for user action or timeout

Tags: ansible

How can I wait for 30sec OR a user interaction in Ansible?

I have the following playbook at the moment:

```
 - name: "Test"
   hosts: localhost
   tasks:    
     - name: wait
       wait_for:
         timeout: 30
```

but you can't press return to cancel the waiting time.

I also have unsuccessfully try the following solution:

```
 - name: "Test"
   hosts: localhost
   tasks:    
     - name: wait
       wait_for:
         pause:
         prompt: Press return to continue. Press Ctrl+c and then "a" to abort
         timeout: 30
```

but pause is not a valide option for wait_for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation says:

You can use ctrl+c if you wish to advance a pause earlier than it is set to expire or if you need to abort a playbook run entirely. **To continue early press ctrl+c and then c**. To abort a playbook press ctrl+c and then a.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to set up the continue on enter? Otherwise I'll just display a message to press ctrl+c and then c

Comment: no you cant.. or you have to build your own module

Comment: by defaut enter = continue and break the pause